# Jquery filtering and sorting

Tags: jquery, list, angularjs, sorting

I am new to programming and javascript. I created the tab menu using JQuery. Here is my fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cg085b/35NJc)

I have tried to use the

```
ng-repeat="chart in charts|filter:{category: 'Where'}
```

loop with this to get the charts in the correct tab, but it doesn't work.

How would I get the charts to filter in to the correct tab?

I appreciate all help.

Comment: Have you used angularjs before? It looks like you haven't. I would run through a tutorial so that you understand binding and controllers in particular. You don't have to use angular to filter these. Google jquery filter and you will find some code.

Comment: I'm really confused. I want to iterate through the json array and have the category of the entries determine which tab the icon appears under on the html page.

Answer (score 0):

A quick look at your fiddle makes me think that you haven't made the transition from jQuery properly yet.  You seem to be doing lots of initialisation inside `$(document).ready()` but you don't really need to do this with AngularJS.

I haven't used them, but the angular-ui bootstrap directives should handle the initialisation for you - just just need to declare them in the right way in your view(s).  All of your logic to query APIs, handle click events, etc. should be inside an AngularJS controller.

As someone has already said - it's probably worth running through a simple tutorial.

Comment: I am running through this one https://www.google.com/#q=angularjs+tutorial
Can you recommend any others?

Comment: I think the examples in the AngularJS docs are a decent place to start http://angularjs.org

Comment: Thank you. I will give them a try.